# rpm spec file not able to find installed libraries during jenkins build: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found

Tags: rpm, packaging, rpmbuild, centos8

I am not able to figure out why the files specified under %files in rpm spec file is not able to find the installed files, let me explain:

The installed files that I intend to package exists in location:

```
-- Installing: /home/jenkins-build/build/workspace/ceph-dev-new-build/ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_DIST/centos8/DIST/centos8/MACHINE_SIZE/gigantic/release/17.0.0-4522-g564a2672/rpm/el8/BUILDROOT/ceph-17.0.0-4522.g564a2672.el8.x86_64/usr/lib64/libjaegertracing.so.0
-- Installing: /home/jenkins-build/build/workspace/ceph-dev-new-build/ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_DIST/centos8/DIST/centos8/MACHINE_SIZE/gigantic/release/17.0.0-4522-g564a2672/rpm/el8/BUILDROOT/ceph-17.0.0-4522.g564a2672.el8.x86_64/usr/lib64/libjaegertracing.so.0.6.1
```

I want to package them in libjaeger package for that I have specified in spec file:

```
%if %{with jaeger}
%files -n libjaeger
%{_libdir}/libopentracing.so.*
%{_libdir}/libthrift.so.*
%{_libdir}/libjaegertracing.so.*
%post -n libjaeger -p /sbin/ldconfig
%postun -n libjaeger -p /sbin/ldconfig
%endif
```

_libdir being `/usr/lib64` from what I understand, since the installed path %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/filename it should be able to find the files as for other packages in the project the path seems to work, but I hit:

```
    Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /usr/lib64/libjaegertracing.so.0
   /usr/lib64/libjaegertracing.so.0.6.1
```

Successfully packaged file:

```
-- Installing: /home/jenkins-build/build/workspace/ceph-dev-new-build/ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_DIST/centos8/DIST/centos8/MACHINE_SIZE/gigantic/release/17.0.0-4522-g564a2672/rpm/el8/BUILDROOT/ceph-17.0.0-4522.g564a2672.el8.x86_64/usr/lib64/libosd_tp.so.1
```

```
%{_libdir}/libosd_tp.so*
```

I have tried existing solutions, on google search :(
I am not sure how to proceed debugging, since it's jenkins build, the time for iterating and understanding is not something I want to get into, cmake/packaging experts can you give some debugging tips.

Thanks!

Comment: You can check its value by running the command `rpm --eval="%{_libdir}"`. Are you sure `%{with jaeger}` is true?

Comment: resolved now, it getting install in /usr/ path instead of %{buildroot}/usr/ path

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reply, I was curious ;) So rpmbuild was run as root, which is not recommended and this is one of the reason.